# MatPagination: mat-table does not update item limit when changing MatPaginator

Tags: angular5, angular-material2, angularfire2

I am trying to paginate my table. 
I have the full implementation of [Angular Material Table with Pagination](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination)(https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#pagination)

Since I am using Angularfire2 my dataSource is an Observable.

```
this.items = this.itemsCollection.valueChanges();
```

I read that I have to use

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Item>;
```

to create a working connection between table and paginator.

I populate the dataSource by

```
let subscription = this.items.subscribe(
      newData => { this.dataSource.data = newData });
```

and update the dataSource's paginator by

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

where this.paginator is defined by

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator
```

like explained in Angular Material's components doc.

The paginator(mat-paginator) is working fine. However, my issue is that the table does not refresh and continues to show all values. Initial values to 'this.paginator' are also not passed to the table limit.

I found a known [bug](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/8381), but I am not sure if that applies to my problem...

Can anyone help me out?

Thank you in advanced!!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

I found an easy solution for my problem by using the Angular Pipe at mat-table. I added the slice pipe like this:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataObservable | async | slice: a:b">
```

and in my data component I was listening to the change event of the HTML Element "mat-paginator"

```
(page)="changePage($event)"
```

In my component I can easily set the sliced data

```
a = 0;
b = this.limit;
changePage(ev) {
  console.log(  ev );
  this.a = ev.pageIndex * ev.pageSize;
  this.b = this.a + ev.pageSize;
  console.log(this.a);
  console.log(this.b);
}
```